pyenv wont activate virtual env
Trying to activate a pyenv:
pyenv activate sintel_env

returns this error:
Failed to activate virtualenv.

Perhaps pyenv-virtualenv has not been loaded into your shell properly.
Please restart current shell and try again.

However, the bashrc file has this lines:
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

What else can I try?
